# Regaining Google PageRank

Tags: pagerank

My companys site was down for about a week due to domain expiration :(

This has hurt our page rank...keywords that used to result in the company's website showing up, no longer do so...

Is there something i can do to mitigate this damage? or do i just have to wait for Google to sort things out with time?

Your input would be appreciated

Comment: Did you check what Google Webmaster Tools says about your site? Maybe you find some useful hints there or can supply a sitemap.... www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your website will slowly climb back-up to (or close to) you're original positions for the various keywords.

Make sure this doesn't happen more often, especially not in the coming months. If Googlebots continues to get bad responses it will remove your listing. Once G hits the site a few times and sees that things are perfectly fine things should slowly get back to what they were.

Have you verified yourself as an owner in Google Webmaster Tools? Check your inbox there to see if G dropped you a message about the website being down.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you'll just have to wait until Google's spider drops by again and fixes things. If you're registered for Google Analytics, I'd check if Google has left hints for you there, but that's about it.

Besides good readability for crawlers, good keywords, loads of links pointing to your site and all the other SEO-stuff that's out there (which probably is what you already did) there's not really anything you can do to regain your site's ranking right away. (Reporting your site to search enginges can even result in the opposite of the desired results.)